# Use IP or TCP packet length to analyze how much data transferred

Tags: networking, tcp, pcap, tcpdump, dpkt

I am pretty new to network traffic. I am trying to get the size of data transferred every second in the internet traffic. I downloaded one pcap file, and I'm using tcpdump to analyze it. By running

```
 tcpdump -tttt -v -r sample.pcap
```

I get some records like below:

```
21:00:00.539514 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 118, id 0, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 32)
111.195.18.190 > host-203-203-22-140.net: ICMP echo reply, id 11884, seq 4803, length 12
```

According to the tutorial (http://packetpushers.net/masterclass-tcpdump-interpreting-output/), the first length (32) is the entire IP packet length, and the second length (12) is the TCP packet length.

I want to know how much data transferred between two hosts. Which one should I use, IP length, TCP length or something else?

Comment: At what network layer? Layer-2 has a header, layer-3 has a header, layer-4 has a header, an application protocol may have a header.

Comment: @RonMaupin Sorry, I have no idea about network layer. What I mean is the actual data transferred during this process.

Comment: What do you mean "actual data"? Can you show examples?

Comment: @kaitoy Sorry, my previous explanation was confusing. What I mean is just all data (everything) transferred between two hosts, such as sender/receiver address, the data that sender want to send out (maybe a video, a message, a picture, etc). I don't understand why TCP and IP packets have the different length. Do they contain different information?

Answer (score 0):

An application data (maybe a video, a message, a picture, etc) is sent with a few headers of lower layers (TCP header (layer 4), IPv4 header (layer 3), Ethernet header (layer 2), etc.).
A TCP packet is an application data + TCP header, an IPv4 packet is a TCP packet + an IPv4 header, and so.

IP packet length is TCP packet length + IP header length. This is why the first length and the second length are different.

Headers may be changed by network devices between the two hosts and so it's no way to think about how much data transferred between the two.
If you want to know the length of each packet in the pcap file, run `tcpdump -e -r sample.pcap` and see the first length of each line.